Anychart : How to add styles to cells with no data?
How can I add styles to cells with no data? In the documentation I only found the noData prop, but thats when there is no data at all, not just no data for single cells.
```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    var data = getData();

    var chart = anychart.heatMap(data);

    // Set width bound
    chart.width('50%');

    // Set height bound
    chart.height('30%');

    chart.title('Set chart width and height');
  
    chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();
});

function getData() {
    return [
        {x: 'Cal', y: '2004', heat: 1704211},
        {x: 'Cal', y: '2005', heat: 2782680},
        {x: 'Cal', y: '2006', heat: 2992679},
        {x: 'Il', y: '2004', heat: 727914},
        {x: 'Il', y: '2005', heat: 1150659},
        {x: 'Ils', y: '2006', heat: 1134085}, //as of now for "Ils" and years 2004&2005 it would be just empty slot
        {x: 'Massachusetts', y: '2004', heat: 238819},
        {x: 'Massachusetts', y: '2005', heat: 157719},
        {x: 'Massachusetts', y: '2006', heat: 887169},
        {x: 'New York', y: '2004', heat: 1667969},
        {x: 'New York', y: '2005', heat: 2763503},
        {x: 'New York', y: '2006', heat: 3151022},
        {x: 'Texas', y: '2004', heat: 219967},
        {x: 'Texas', y: '2005', heat: 3732889},
        {x: 'Texas', y: '2006', heat: 4185098}
    ]
}

